# How do you redirect user to settings after denying permissions for Save Image from UIActivityController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller, phphotolibrary

After a user takes a photo in my app, there is a UIUserActivity that is presented that allows users to save and image. A pop up comes up and asks for permission to write the photo to the users photo album. However, if the user denies there is no way to prompt the user to be redirected to the photo library. PHPhoto authorization status is always returning undetermined even though permissions were already asked for. I am looking for a few things to be satisfied:

1. the user should be able to deny but continue to be prompted to give permission to the app if they want to save their photo.
2. if the user denies, I want the option of "save photo" to remain in the UIUserActivity as a potential option

How can I accomplish this?

I've tried using the PHPhotoLibrary authorization status, but it always returns undetermined. I've tried checking for .undetermined and using the PHPhotoLibrary to request access to the user's camera roll, however if the user denies at this point then the option to save photo is completely removed from the UIUserActivity pop up.

code:

```
activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = { activity, success, items, error in
    if success {
        if let activity = activity {
        ...
        case .saveToCameraRoll:
           handleCameraRollPermission()
```

```swift
func handleCameraRollPermission(status: PHAuthorizationStatus? = nil, completion: @escaping ((Bool) -> Void)) {
        let authorizationStatus = status ?? PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
        switch authorizationStatus {
        case .denied, .restricted:
            showPermissionMissingAlert(completion: completion)
        case .notDetermined:
            PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { (status) in
                switch(status) {
                case .denied, .restricted, .notDetermined:
                    self.showPermissionMissingAlert(completion: completion)
                default:
                    break
                }
            }
        default:
            completion(true)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit overdoing it, but you could create a custom action section for the activityView. You can find more about that [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/118/uiactivityviewcontroller-by-example) and scroll down to the `Adding a custom action` section.

Basically you would make a custom save button that would persist regardless of permission status. When it is tapped you can check their authorization status and go from there.